# "All Eyez on Me" iPhone question gets 38k views in 3 days?

Tags: bug

Can someone explain how [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74927/why-is-there-an-iphone-in-all-eyez-on-me) got 37,642 views in 3 days? Is this an error with the stats, or are there legitimately that many views? 
 [image: Screenshot]

Comment: Probably better asked at meta.stackexchange

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/how-are-the-number-of-views-in-a-question-calculated

Comment: It's not entirely impossible with a Hot Network Question, but then it would also have a ton of upvotes (be they deserved or not), otherwise it wouldn't even land in the HNQ list. But this score-to-views ratio is indeed really odd. I'd expect some kind of external link that brings in a ton of non-SE viewers.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Yes. Many of them are from non-SE people. If you type "All eyez on me iphone", the first result was that question. That iphone issue was greatly discussed by critics of the film. It was a biopic of some famous personality.

Comment: @Paulie_D: Question is not about how stats work. It's about this particular question having approximately 1500 times more views than questions asked around the same time.

Comment: @SS: I'm surprised and pleased that, with all the press that was getting, M&TV managed to get so far up the rankings.  I guess this question ended up being more about SEO than stats, lol.